# EC2 `UserData` execution callback?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have a Cloudformation template which creates a VPC/Subnet and launches a single EC2 machine within it -

https://gist.github.com/jhw/9c595edb615381780a2ba76791722fc3#file-stack-yaml

The template also contains some EC2 `UserData` which installs Cloudwatch and CodeDeploy user agents on that machine.

The template works fine but I'm struggling how to get notified as to when the `UserData` has actually been executed - it seems that the EC2 machine will say "ready" but only *then* starts to execute `UserData`, which subsequently takes a couple of minutes due to the need to load/install different packages.

The only way I have been able to get visibility on how `UserData` execution is going is to dump the EC2 machine level logs, but this is far from perfect as the logs don't seem to be available until the `UserData` has *completed* execution - if you try to download them prior to successful execution then you just get an empty file.

So my "automated" routine for detecting whether the machine is *really* ready is to fetch the logs on a timed loop, and then try and detect certain keywords in those logs.

This feels, ahem, suboptimal :-/

Is there a better way of getting notified when `UserData` may have completed execution ? Some kind of callback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CreationPolicy Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html) Associate the CreationPolicy attribute with a resource to prevent its status from reaching create complete until AWS CloudFormation receives a specified number of success signals or the timeout period is exceeded.

In Instance CloudFormation use CreationPolicy with Count=1:

```
CreationPolicy:
  ResourceSignal:
    Count: '1'
    Timeout: PT15M
```

and then send this signal as a last line of the UserData script:

```
cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MyEC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon on this one. How do u install `cfn-signal` on the EC2 instance ? I tried the above but got `cfn-signal not found` initially.  Then noticed i could `apt-get install heat-cfntools` to get `cfn-signal`. But now getting `cfn-signal: error: unrecognized arguments: --stack --resource MyEC2Instance --region eu-west-1`. Do I have the right `cfn-signal` ?

Comment: Most likely not the right one. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html `yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap` need to be in your UserData

Comment: Works! Although I ended up installing via pip as per here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230535. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your EC2 instance's OS is systemd based, you can use "After" in [Unit] section to define an executable/service that should be started after 'cloud-final' is up.

The unit section should look similar to this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Example-Service
After=cloud-final.service
```

I found a similar answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/871328/start-service-after-aws-user-data-has-run

Here our a few links to help with bootstrapping and it provides examples:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_user_data_scripts.html
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started